# How to grab URL content using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I find **246497** in following url using regex -

https://www.google.in/product/246497/Do-Re-Me-Kitten-Princess-Pink-Frock

the pattern will be https://www.google.in/product/**/xyz

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookahead based regex.

```
str.match(/[^\/]*(?=\/[^\/]*$)/)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oY1aL6/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
window.location.href.split("/")[4]
```

it will grab what you need

Comment: btw, he requires regex version. but your solution looks more understandable though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression:

```
/^https:\/\/www\.google\.in\/product\/([^\/]*)\/[\w-]*$/
```

Group 1 will contain 246497.